# Do I need a Schengen transit visa to travel from India to the US with transit at Frankfurt and London

Tags: indian-citizens, schengen-visas, transit-visas, london, frankfurt

I am an Indian citizen and have a valid US visa. I am planning to travel to the US from India with layovers at Frankfurt and London. The itinerary is

`BOM -> FRA -> LHR -> EWR`

I came across an [article](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/news/explaining-transit-schengen-visa-requirement-for-indians) which mentioned that I need a Schengen transit visa. I also came across another [article](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/transit-schengen-visa/) which mentions that the transit visa requirements can be waived off if I have a valid US visa.

I just wanted to check if anyone has any knowledge about this or has been in a similar situation? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UK is outside the Schengen area. So, this itenary shouldn't be an issue as long as you stay within the international transit area of the airports.

In detail:

If you had selected a flight that has layovers in two Schengen countries, it would have been an issue, as Schengen-Schengen flights is like a domestic flight and you have to clear immigration, which require a Schengen visa. Since one layover is in UK, which is outside Schengen area, you can stay in the international transit area and you don't need transit visas.

Comment: With a valid US visa, Indian citizens do not require a Schengen Transit visa for Frankfurt International Airport (FRA). [Airport transit visas - Federal Foreign Office](https://uk.diplo.de/uk-en/02/visa/airport-transit-visas/2442170)

Comment: And the same is true of the LHR transit: no visa is necessary provided the Indian traveler has a US visa (like the OP) has had their hold luggage checked through from BOM to EWR, and will leave LHR the same day as they arrive. See [this UK govt page](https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa) for more details.

Comment: Sometimes you may need to enter the Schengen area to catch the connecting flight. For example, four students flying from India-Paris-Amsterdam-Chicago were denied boarding because their Paris-Amsterdam flight was inside the Schengen Area (https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/bengaluru/bengaluru-four-bound-for-us-denied-boarding-over-schengen-visa/articleshow/92310037.cms)